# DbUpdateException occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I get an Entity Framework error, pretty generic, like most EF errors: "An unhandled error of type System.Entity.Data.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException occurred in EntityFramework.dll. An error occurred while updating the entries".
Any thoughts on how to handle this please?

Here is the context - I have 3 projects, I want my database to be created through the Code First approach. I approximately followed the steps from the official documentation but gave my own example:

1. ConsoleApp1: create as console application; install-package EntityFramework
2. SongDomain.Classes: create as console application; Properties - Output Type: change to Class Library; remove App.config
   Add Classes.cs
3. SongDomain.DataModel: create as console application; Properties - Output Type: change to Class Library; remove App.config; Add SongContext.cs

Classes.cs // define the Model here;

```
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace SongDomain.Classes
{

    public class Song
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public Album Album { get; set; }
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public List<Genre> Genre { get; set; }
    }
    public class Album
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Song> Songs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Genre
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<Song> Song { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, the context class:

```
using SongDomain.Classes;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace SongDomain.DataModel
{
    public class SongContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Song> Songs { get; set; } // Song is needed, so have to reference the Classes project
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The context derives from System.Data.Entity.DbContext and exposes a typed DbSet for each class in our model.

I am implementing the Main method in Program.cs:

```
using SongDomain.Classes;
using SongDomain.DataModel;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new SongContext())
            {
                // Create and save a new song
                Console.Write("Enter new song: ");
                var name = Console.ReadLine();

                var s = new Song { Name = name };
                db.Songs.Add(s);
                db.SaveChanges();

                     
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think? At first glance at least am I doing something wrong? I haven't given it any details about the database because I want it to be generated through the code like the documentation suggests it's possible (I know in a real life scenario it's very unlikely that I would need not give the db configuration in a settings file)

PS. Yes I tried adding attributes to field Id from Song like this:
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

... same problem

I was expecting the db to be auto generated but doesn't happen

Comment: You still need to configure EF with a connection string either in the app.config or via code so that it knows what and where the database server is.  If you are getting an exception also put those details in your question to narrow down the potential problems.

Comment: What is the inner exception?

Comment: But the official documentation suggests it's not necessary to add connection string: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx , apparently EF should be able to manage without them, and I wanted to test just that, "If SQL Express isn’t available then Code First will try and use LocalDb (installed by default with Visual Studio 2012)
The database is named after the fully qualified name of the derived context, in our case that is CodeFirstNewDatabaseSample.BloggingContext".

DevilSuichiro, I didn't find the inner exception.. i'll check again. thanks both!